# Calling service in $stateprovider's controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For now I can execute my service in my AppCtrl but this is not right. Because the service is needed only when the user nagivated to page2. How can I execute my service when the page2 state is active? I tried resolve but couldn't get it work properly.

```
    app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {


        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');

        $stateProvider.state('home', {
          url: '/home',
          templateUrl: 'home.html'
        })

        $stateProvider.state('page2', {
          url: '/page2/:topicId',
          templateUrl: 'page2.html'
        // call my service here?
    });

    });

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', 'getTopicContent', function($scope,getTopicContent){
    getTopicContent.request().success(function(data){
        $scope.myList = data;
    });
}]);


app.factory('getTopicContent', ['$http', function($http){

    var query = function() {
        return $http({
            url: "http://www.corsproxy.com/mydata.me/level1/list.php",
            method: "GET"
        })
    }

    return {
        request : function(){
            return query();
        }

    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a controller for your page and inject service there.

```
$stateProvider.state('page2', {
      url: '/page2/:topicId',
      templateUrl: 'page2.html',
      controller: 'Page2Ctrl'
});
```

Then your controller would look like

```
app.controller('Page2Ctrl', ['$scope', 'getTopicContent', function($scope,getTopicContent){
    getTopicContent.request().success(function(data){
        $scope.myList = data;
    });
}]);
```

if you want to try resolve, You can do something like this

```
$stateProvider.state('page2', {
      url: '/page2/:topicId',
      templateUrl: 'page2.html',
      controller: 'Page2Ctrl',
      resolve: {
          content: getTopicContent.request().success(function(data){
                      return $scope.myList = data;
                   });
      }
});
```

Then in your Page2Ctrl you can verify this content

```
app.controller('Page2Ctrl', ['$scope', 'getTopicContent', function($scope, content){
    if (content) {
        $scope.content = content;
    }    
}]);
```

Comment: I got a Page2Ctrl is not defined. In my html where should I include ng-controller?

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module App due to:
ReferenceError: Page2Ctrl is not defined

Comment: Did you include the file in your index.html? You dont need to use ng-controller separately in html

Comment: ops I forgot to put '' for the controller, ur code worked fine. TQ very much!

Comment: if I don't use the resolve, how can I pass the $stateParams to Page2Ctrl?

Comment: You can simply inject $stateparams in your Page2Ctrl. and in your contoller you can get topicId by ``$stateParams. topicId``